# How to copy micro SD card from a sealed raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pi-2, ssh, sd-card

I have received a raspberry pi 2 as the followings. But its micros SD card is sealed strongly to the board.

[image]

And let's see the left side of it.

[image]

I am thinking if we can read the SD card from other Pins such GPIO on this raspberry Pi 2? Without damaging the board.

It looks they have sealed the board without soldering but some chemical glues. Before melting these glues, I am seeking the possibility of reading its SD card in some other ways.

Do you have some ideas?

Many thanks!

Appreciate your help!

---

updated

We don't have the SSH password yet. It's a Pi as a router (blackbox).

How would you think ?

---

updated

I have read the output from its TTL console via a USB -> TTL at baud rate 115200.

Here's the output in detail:

> pastebin(dot)com/Y7Xg5WRg

Linux version 3.18.16-v7 (root@builder)

but the TTL console did not provide user login promote. The output ends and the end.

Comment: LOL , even the rootfs is encrypted ... somebody **really** wants to stop you. Good luck - perhaps try debugging via JTAG ? Don't ask me how though ...

Comment: @flakeshake you are welcome. I have taken the SD card out. No more skills but with a sharp knife... Yes it's encrypted. Now I am figuring how to decrypt the volume now. It's can't be harder than getting into (Black opposite house). So it can not be stopped.

Comment: Glad you got it out.  Before working with it, I recommend you go with the OP title and make a copy.  I posted an answer below about using Win32DiskImager as being by far the simplest way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `SD Copy` which is available in the GUI of latest Raspbian to make a copy to an empty SD Card mounted in a SD Card reader.

You can also use `rsync` to copy to a mounted HDD or network drive.

Comment: Sadly we don't have the SSH password. It's a Pi as a router (blackbox). Do you have some ideas?

Comment: @dotslash If you don't have access to the system (through keyboard or `ssh`) or know the `sudo` password your options are limited - presumably the intention of the person who secured it.

Answer (score 1):

You could carefully cut off part of the bit that sticks out to ease the extraction process.

The Pi 2's SD card traces are within an inner layer as far as I can tell, and there are no test points for them (possibly intentionally, as they are present on the Pi 1 and Pi Zero as PP14 to PP19).

If the root filesystem is encrypted, where is the encryption key stored? More than likely it's in the SD card as well, making decryption possible. Might be compiled into the kernel. They might have made the key a function of the Pi's serial number and/or MAC address. Note that only firmware released before 7 Feb 2015 allows passing a custom serial number to the kernel.

https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/357

The kernel image will have to be on the boot partition, which is unencrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have the card released, then the easiest way to duplicate it is to use [Win32DiskImager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/).

It allows you to read the contents of your drive as a `.img` file.

Then the `.img` file can be written to another SD card of sufficient size.

Very easy to use, and works well.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Ask the person who gave you the machines for the contents of the card and/or the root password.
2. Buy a new Pi. If you're doing this just to recover the hardware, it's really not worth it.

Comment: I updated the details of this question. Received output from the Pi 2 via TTL console (serial port). Do you know how to read the sd card?

Answer (score 0):

If you DO manage to get access to an account (root preferred, of course) you can copy the card out to a file on a usb drive with a dd command :

dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/sda1/mysteryPI.img bs=4096

Otherwise you must attack in hardware; try dremelling off the end of the expoxy, maybe then you can extract the card.

When you hook up a monitor, do you see anything interesting as it boots?

Comment: Thank man. I took the SD card out with a sharp knife. And the sd card is alright. Problem solved. Otherwise I would try to solder some cables to read it(lots of labour work).

Answer (score 0):

I see that the hdmi port is open. If the usb ports are also open, you can just plug the Raspberry Pi into a tv or monitor and plug in a keyboard. You could use dd to copy it to a usb drive like docwebhead mentioned. No need for ssh or anything like that, just a plain ol' keyboard right in the usb port.

> dd if=/dev/mmcblk0 of=/dev/sda1/mysteryPI.img bs=4096